# How to design a multiple instance application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, rabbitmq

Task: Need to create a console app using c#.net that can be run on multiple instances. (For scalability purpose)

Now this is easy if you create a straight forward app. My problem right now is on my app I have a global variable. To give you an idea of what this app is. This is a little program that receives JSON messages(I used RabbitMQ for the messaging part). The message that it receives will then be stored on a global varriable. Now, this makes it difficult to run the app on a multiple instances. Because if you run more than 1 instance of the app, It could be that the message will be received on the other app. That is because of the Round Robin behavior of RabbitMQ. (Creating Exchange, or routing key is not an option.)

I have tried using shared memory or MemoryMappedFile, but that doesn't work either.

One other thing that I have in mind is to use a DB. But I need good design to do this.
If someone knows a pattern, an example or whatever references. Let me know.

Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on your intent? Do you wish to handle messages with multiple instances or not? Do you want to parallelize something or not?

Comment: Hi @Dusan, More like of handling messages on multiple instances. (in a way). So here is the thing, I am using RabbitMQ. My application is consuming from a Queue. If you run multiple instance of your application, that means you will have 2 consumers in your queue. Now, when messages comes in to that queue. It will go to your 1st app, and when another message comes in, it will go to the 2nd app. (Round Robin Fashion). Now it could be that the one you will get on the 2nd app is the same message, so I need a way to look up to check if that message already exist using ID.

Comment: If the consumers are receiving messages in a RR fashion then how might the second app end up with the same message as the first app? Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. So it goes like this, when message comes to the app, it has a unique ID. And that is what I am keeping together with some other data. Now another message will come, that message could be the same unique ID but has different status. Thanks for the reply btw.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `MemoryMappedFiles`, they look like the simplest way to do this (ignoring the DB).
I am not sure why did no do the job for you?

Each instance of application would "register" itself in this file and allocate the portion of file in which to write the data.
When you receive the message, check the data of the other instances which is stored across the file.

You can use Mutex for all of the operations (instance register, write, read) - it will guarantee you have the consistent picture of the data.

Comment: Hi Dusan, I don't think MemoryMappedFiles will work for me. Even if I can make my first try work it will not still be preferable. Because another instance of the app could be running on a different machine.

Comment: Hi Shen. In that case you will have to use some kind of shared resource. In my opinion, the database would be the painless and simplest approach as they solve concurrent access out of the box.

Comment: However, if you wish to use your custom solution, then in some situations you will need to handle concurrent data in a proper way.

I suggest you to take a look at the Petreson's Algorithm as a starting point - it would probably solve you the concurrency in an easy and simple way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If memory mapped files really do not work for you how about changing the architecture slightly. Have the main console application (sort of server), this can spawn off other console apps (sort of clients) as needed. They can then use [Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx) (or any other inter process communication mechanism) to check with the server if the message has already been processed, if not they add it to the list or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture you need is:

1 Controller.  This is responsible for reading the message out of the queue and assigning it.

1+ Handlers.   The controller will instantiate one or more handlers as necessary based on your load.  The handlers should have a definite start / end.  Meaning you execute one, passing the message in, and it completely exits once that message is properly processed.

---

Or, just go buy Biztalk or a similar message processing app server.  That's what those things are built for.

Your primary concern is really going to be around reliability; specifically, knowing that a message was actually processed.  So, you'll need a storage mechanism that survives hardware failures (such as a database), a communication mechanism between the controller and handlers (could be anything) and some way of responding back assuming long running processes.  Probably a heart beat piece to ensure that one of the handlers hasn't just gone belly up.  Certainly a way to reprocess the message, perhaps automatically, in case of failure.  Finally, you'll need a way to throttle the handlers so that you only run X number simultaneously in order to prevent the system from being overwhelmed.

In short, this is not a "simple" app, unless the messages are such that they can be dropped, ignored or otherwise not processed.